# How to count the number of rows with NA values in specific columns?

Tags: r

I have a `dataframe` with 502543 obs. of  9 variables including the ID (which is repeated several times). I need to count how many rows have `NA` values in all variables except in `ID`. I don't want to delete this ID column, as later I will need to count `n_distinct(ID)`, that's why I am looking for a method to count rows with NA values in all columns except in this one.

My dataframe looks like this sample:

```
ID neckpain backpain kneepain
1  Yes       NA       NA
2  NA        NA       NA
3  Yes       Yes      Yes
2  NA        NA       NA
3  Yes       Yes      Yes
4  NA        NA       NA
```

> The outcome I'm trying to obtain would be
> nrows: 3

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you all of you for your answers. I don't have enough reputation to thank by voting, but thanks to you I could find what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping in the tidyverse world (assumed since you wanted to use n_distinct)

```
library(tidyverse)

##Your data
data <- tibble(ID = c(1,2,3,2,3,4),
               neckpain = c('Yes',NA,'Yes',NA,'Yes',NA),
               backpain = c(NA,NA,'Yes',NA,'Yes',NA),
               kneepain = c(NA,NA,'Yes',NA,'Yes',NA)) 

##Pull out ones are missing across ID and count the rows if you want to cherry pick columns
nrow(data %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(row_total = sum(is.na(neckpain),
                         is.na(backpain),
                         is.na(kneepain))) %>% 
  filter(row_total == 3))

[1] 3

##Or if you just want to do it across all rows as noted in the comments
nrow(data %>% 
       mutate(row_total = rowSums(is.na(.[2:4]))) %>% 
       filter(row_total == 3))
[1] 3
```

Comment: If the data has many columns, you need to type `sum(is.na(col1), is.na(col2), ...)` many times. It's not a good programing idea.

Comment: @DarrenTsai - Agreed, added additional method. Original one is more suited for cherry picking columns to investigate.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `ID` is your first column, then

```
sum(rowSums(is.na(df[-1])) == ncol(df[-1]))
#[1] 3
```

If you want to look at it from the opposite direction (i.e. 0 columns with non-NA), then you can use suggestion by @RonakShah,

```
sum(rowSums(!is.na(df[-1])) == 0)
```

Comment: Another way : `sum(rowSums(!is.na(data[-1])) == 0)`

Answer (score 2):

For a supplement, it's a `dplyr` solution.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter(across(-ID, is.na)) %>% count()

#   n
# 1 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner:

```
sum(apply(df1[-1], 1, function(x) all(is.na(x))))
#[1] 3
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
ID neckpain backpain kneepain
1  Yes       NA       NA
2  NA        NA       NA
3  Yes       Yes      Yes
2  NA        NA       NA
3  Yes       Yes      Yes
4  NA        NA       NA
", header = TRUE)
```